# Why does the interaction hamiltonian not commute with itself at different times?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hamiltonian, commutator

If you have a poincare invariant Hamiltonian $H$, then the Hamiltonian must commute with itself at different times and not explicitly depend on time. If the Hamiltonian $H$ can be written as $H$ = $H_{0}$ + $H_{I}$ where $H_{0}$ is the free field Hamiltonian and $H_{I}$ is the interaction Hamiltonian, I am having a difficult time understanding why in general $H_{I}$ does not commute with itself at different times, since it will also not explicitly depend on time. I can see how it wont commute with the full Hamiltonian so it might evolve in time, but I don't see why it wont necessarily commute with itself at different times.

Answer (score 2):

In the Heisenberg picture, you decompose $H = H_0+V$ where each term is considered as time independent. However, in the interaction picture, since you first apply the Heisenberg picture on the non interacting part, $H_I$ becomes $V_I = e^{-itH_0}Ve^{itH_0}$ which now has a time dependence. In general, $V_I$ will not commute with itself at different times precisely because $H_I$ and $H_0$ don't commute in general.

Take for example a forced harmonic oscillator using creation/annihilation operators $a,a^\dagger$ satisfying $[a,a^\dagger]=1$ with $H_0 = a^\dagger a$ and $H_I = \alpha^* a+\alpha a^\dagger$ with $\alpha$ a complex number (possibly time dependent). In the interaction picture, $a\to a_I(t) = e^{-it}a$. They therefore satisfy the new commutations:

$$
[a_I(t),a_I(t')] = 0 \\
[a_I(t),a_I(t')^\dagger] = e^{-i(t-t')}
$$

The hamiltonian becomes $\tilde H_I(t) = \alpha^* a_I+\alpha a_I^\dagger$. You can check using the previous commutations:

$$
[H_I(t),H_I(t')] = \alpha^*(t)\alpha(t')e^{-i(t-t')}-\alpha(t)\alpha^*(t')e^{-i(t'-t)}
$$

(which is indeed imaginary) This is why to solve the interaction picture you'll need to appeal to a time ordered exponential, which is usually calculated perturbatively using Dyson's formula. Note that in this simple example, the time ordered exponential can be analytically calculated using the displacement operator.

Hope this helps.